# What teas with natural caffeine can be used for lemon tea?

Tags: tea

I like to drink hot, naturally caffeinated tea (so no added caffeine please) in which one entire lemon or lime is prodded, pulped, and steeped. What kinds of naturally caffeinated tea would correspond?

A Google search desultorily yields 'black tea', a term which is too vague, and 'Earl Grey' tea?

Comment: Hello! I'm afraid that this is basically a pairing question: as I understand it, you are asking "which tea goes well with lemon". This is a subjective question, and would only result in people telling you their favorite tea, so a poll question. As with any Stack Exchange site, it is not a type of question we can take, sorry. Just use whichever tea *you* like.

Comment: I think black tea is a perfectly fine answer; pretty much any black tea sounds fine. I'm not sure why it's too vague. There's not always only one really specific correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of a "experiment and find out" kind of thing, there being such a large variety of teas in the world.

Earl Grey and lemon is a classic pairing, but a whole lemon might be too much. Jasmine green is smooth and pairs well with lemon, but not lime. Either and any citrus fruit typically pairs well with Yerba Mate.

but the list is huge. I would recommend going to check out your local tea shoppe and seeing what they have.

Comment: +1 for last sentence in particular. A local tea shoppe will be delighted with the interesting question, opportunity to discuss tea varieties, and your business!